# How to implement string.codepoints for pre ruby 1.9.1

Tags: ruby

For backward compatibility reasons I want to implement the `String#codepoints` ruby method (introduced in `1.9.1`).

I am thinking

```
def codepoints(str)
    str.split('').map(&:ord)
end
```

but I am concerned that `#ord` will not work properly with earlier versions of ruby.

Comment: Install the [backports](https://github.com/marcandre/backports) gem and `require backports/1.9.1/string/codepoints`. It uses `unpack('U*')` under the hood, you can find the source code [here](https://github.com/marcandre/backports/blob/master/lib/backports/1.9.1/string/codepoints.rb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ord` was introduced in Ruby 1.9.1, see [APIDock](https://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_392/String/ord).

For ASCII strings you  can use [`#bytes`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/String.html#method-i-bytes), for Unicode [it won't behave in the same way as `#codepoints`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40849265/bytes-vs-codepoints-in-ruby).

In Ruby 1.8.x you can use `?` to get char numeric value, I don't know what to use for 1.9.0.

Btw rubies older than 2.3 are not supported any more, consider upgrading.

Comment: It is not my choice, I am trying pass the CI tests for a pull request on a gem, and passing  ruby 1.8.7 is one of the tests.

Comment: I can't install 1.8.7 to test it, but you can try `string.bytes.map{|b| ?b}`

Comment: Btw I'd consider contacting the gem maintainer and convince them to drop 1.8.7 support

Comment: They are planning to drop it in the next major release, I doubt very much they will do so before then, I expect they have heard that argument many times before.  When I put ```str.bytes.map { |b| ?b }``` I get a rubycop error to the effect that ```Do not use the character literal - using string literal instead.```. I need to pass all rubocop tests as well, so is there a way of expressing this that will not trigger a rubocop error?

Comment: `# rubocop:disable RuleByName` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26342570/rubocop-linelength-how-to-ignore-lines-with-comments

Comment: Thank you, I try this and see their response is.  When finished I may come back and tidy this up.

Comment: @mrzasa: `?b` is equal to `'b'` on Ruby 1.9+ and equal to `97` on Ruby pre-1.9. How is replacing the entire string with 97s going to solve the problem? E.g. `'Hello'.bytes.map {|b| ?b }` is `['b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b']` on Ruby 1.9+ and `[97, 97, 97, 97, 97]` on Ruby 1.8.